# Gas being evacuated out at an infinitesimally small rate

Tags: thermodynamics

I am unable to think about a fact that my textbook used. It said that whenever an ideal gas is evacuated out from a chamber at an infinitesimally small $ volume/time$ rate,  the mass inside the chamber in the small interval $dt  $ remains constant provided the whole process is done isothermally.

I just can't think about it intuitively.  The volume of the gas has decreased by an amount(not matter how much small it is) then how can the mass not lessen by some amount,  say $ dm$  because itis  the moles of the gas that are actually taking up the volume and if I decrease volume, the number of moles must go down and hence the mass also.

Can anybody please help me in thinking about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What sou say is correct.
If we, in an isothermal process, let some moles escape from the chamber, volume decreases by an amount $dV$ and also does mass ($dm$).

But when we are working with ideal gasses, the assumption is that the gas is very dilute so that there is no potential energy because of the particles being near each other. This also means that $dm/dV$ is really small.

So the assumption that the mass will be constant is almost correct and practical.